# WSL: Redirect links to host

Tags: x11, windows, forwarding, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As Windows is missing a nice twitter client I'm using WSL, with X11 forwarding to get Corebird running on my Windows 10 host. The question is: Is it possible to redirect the click on a link within Corebird to open it using the default browser on the host instead of launching WSL's Firefox? I guess I would need a handler which registers for http/https links which I can set using `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`.

Is there something like this already?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking about specific Windows knowledge. Superuser.com seems more suited and might have more people adept of Windows to help you.

Comment: Well ain't this funny. First it's not a programming question for stack overflow. Now it's not a Linux question either..

Comment: Does anything in this question help? https://superuser.com/questions/1262977/open-browser-in-host-system-from-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: Thanks for the hint mark! I will check out if setting the browser environment variable works and report back if it does.